# Django queryset returns different results from shell and server

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Django queryset that gets different results in different situations and I am confused.

```
texts = Text.objects.filter(keywords__icontains=word)
```

The model:

```
class Text(models.Model):

    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    response = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

That call, literally copied, gets the expected results with ./manage.py shell, but doesn't find anything on the server.

It pulls up the result when I call Text.objects.all(), but for some reason the filter, on the server, doesn't find the same result as any other case.

WHY???

Comment: Is this on the same machine with the same settings.py file? If not have you run syncdb on both machines?

Comment: how are you defining `word` on your server (probably in your views.py)? I bet your problem lies there.

Comment: They are on the same machine, using the same settings.py.

Comment: And I am defining word with identical processes in each case, receiving a string in a phrase which I then retrieve the first word with word = body.split(' ')[0]. Is there a better way to get the first word of a string?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because your production database engine is different of your dev one (I assume you are running `manage.py shell` on your local machine) ?

Keep in mind that the behaviour - especially on string matching - may differ [according to your database backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/databases/#sqlite-string-matching).

Or maybe the content of your databases are differents ?

If `manage.py shell` hits the same database, the results should be identicals. Are you sure that your request (from the Webserver) is correct ? Check your database logs.

Comment: I am doing both on the same server, with the same database and backend.  Like I said, objects.all() includes the object I am looking for, with all the right attributes, but when filtering for it, it doesn't come up, on the production site only.